# Is there a way to use "indirect addressing" for JavaScript arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a 2d JavaScript array like this:

```
inventory[1].products
```

where products is an object with elements
`{"itemid":"na", "books":10, "dvds":15, "cds":4}`

I need to be able to set the itemid with something like

```
inventory[1].itemid = "books";
indirectaddress = inventory[1].itemid;
```

and then be able to read the value of the books element with something like:

```
numberofbooks = inventory[1].indirectaddress;
```

Is this possible with JS arrays?  I done some searching and can't find anything, unless I am not using the correct nomenclature.

Comment: Please show an example of the output of `console.log(JSON.stringify(inventory, null, 2))` so that we can see what the actual structure of `inventory` is. I'm guessing it's not actually a 2d array. It's unclear what you mean by indirect addressing.

Comment: `inventory[1].products` isn't a 2d array. Inventory appears to be an array of objects, with a property named `products` whose value is a single object. As @Heretic Monkey requested, can you please post a sample of your data structure.

Comment: The example I gave in the OP was a very simplified example just to get the point across of what I was looking for.  It worked and James provided me with the solution I was looking for.  I am actually using the result in a much, much more complex 3d array.  I had previously marked James's response as the correct solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remember the property name in your indirectaddress variable, and use bracket notation to access "books" property via indirectaddress.

```
indirectaddress = "books";
numberofbooks = inventory[1][indirectaddress];
```

Comment: It might be a good idea to show that this has more to do with addressing properties on objects that indexes in arrays since the OP (and many others) appear to be confused about this...

Comment: Thanks James, that did the trick and was exactly what I needed.  I'm glad you understood what I was talking about.   When I tried that, I had: inventory[1].[indirectaddress].   Removing the . made it work correctly.